# not authorize access to upload directory files except for browser

Tags: php, .htaccess, file-upload

i wrote a script in php to upload a logo picture. It works fine.

But my app is used be several people and they can all upload their logo. So i created this path:
'uploads/IDCLIENT/logo.png'
That's works!

But if in my browser i set the url to: http://mydomain/uploads/IDCLIENT/logo.png, i can see it. If i set to http://mydomain/uploads/ANOTHER_IDCLIENT/logo.png i can see the logo of another user. This is embarassing.

I have a .htaccess file on my root directory:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\/\\?\=]*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA]
```

So i tried to add a htaccess file in the 'uploads' directory:

```
Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
```

This works, i can't see file when i set the url BUT in my app, i can't see file, the logo can't be displayed.

Is there a way to forbid direct access to the uploads directory (when we set a url) AND display files in uploads directory in my HTML files.

Thanks.

Comment: you must be able to separate the images somehow. here you chose to separate them with IDCLIENT, i don't see a problem with that. does each of the clients have their own domain? in which case, you can separate them by domain

Comment: no they don't have their own domain. The problem with id is that it's incremental, if i have the id: 5, i'll try to enter 6 in the url bar and i'll work, i'll see the logo of the other user.

Comment: sigh, hash the number maybe?

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: To expand on your problem:

Using `Deny from all` (as the name suggests) denies **ALL** requests to that particular file/directory you are directing the .htaccess to deny.

You are also denying your server access to the file/directory by doing this too (even your localhost which is 127.0.0.1), so it cannot directly get the image from the folder and display it.

So what do you need to do? You need to allow the server/localhost to access that file/directory directly.

Adding the IP as a whitelisted item by using `allow from 127.0.0.1` underneath your existing two lines of code will allow your localhost direct access.

Comment: i'll try this. I saw on another application on which is possible to upload a picture, i saw in the source code the url of the picture, i copy it and try to navigate to the parent directory and i get a 404 error. How did they do that?

Comment: NOPE! it don't work. I created a .htaccess file in uploads directory: Order Deny,Allow
Deny from all
Allow from 127.0.0.1
And i can't display the logo in my html's source code.

Comment: Or can i use rewrite_url? store logo in uploads/IDCLIENT/logo.png but display 'img/uploads_files/my_logo.png' and if i try to access to 'img/uploads_files' i get a 404 error? No?

Answer (score 0):

A suggestion for this would be to change the IDCLIENT to use a different type of key. I imagine you may be using an incrementing integer.

A good solution would be to use UUID4.

So a url would be like so:  http://mydomain/uploads/619df8f5-24aa-4a70-aa84-dedb1e5eeea5/logo.png

This would make it increasingly difficult if not impossible to guess another client's storage folder.

More information on UUID 4: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universally_unique_identifier#Version_4_.28random.29

PHP Package for UUID 4: https://github.com/ramsey/uuid

Comment: Thanks, i did not know uuid4 could be as serious that it seems to be. I'll read about that. But, i'll need to store this uuid in database for clients.

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:
i modify my .htaccess file in my root directory, i add a line:

```
RewriteEngine on

RewriteRule ^([a-zA-Z0-9\-\_\/\\?\=]*)$ index.php?p=$1 [QSA]

# redirect the request views/img/shared_uploads/ TO views/img/logo
RewriteRule ^views/img/shared_uploads/(.+)$ /views/img/logo/$1 [NC,L,R=302]
```

And if i set the url like this: http://mydomain/views/img/shared_uploads/IDCLIENT/ it don't work.

Thanks for your help.